# MVC model wont accept value from Jquery DateTimePicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model, datetimepicker

I'm pulling my hair out because of this issue. I'm trying to use jquery datetimepicker on my mvc field, but for some reason, the values do not get passed onto the model. If I run with validation on the fields, they state that the values must be a "Date"

Here is my textboxes:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
      @Html.Label("From")
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.From, new {id = "startDate", @class = "form-control"})
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
      @Html.Label("To")
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.To, new {id = "endDate", @class = "form-control"})
</div>
```

My javascript:

```
    $("#startDate").datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY H:00:00',
        locale:'da'
    });
    $("#endDate").datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY H:00:00',
        locale: 'da'
    });
```

And finally my model:

```
public class ScheduleHoursModel
{
    public DateTime From { get; set; }

    public DateTime To { get; set; }

    public bool Recurring { get; set; }
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is the error a client side error (i.e you using `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`) in which case you need to reconfigure the validator (which by default validates date in `MM/dd/yyyy` format. Or is this just a server side error, in which case your server culture does not accept dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format so you need to change the culture or use a custom ModelBinder to bind your dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must reference the outer div and not the textbox itself like this:

```
<div id="startDate">            
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.From)
</div>

$("#startDate").datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY H:00:00',
    locale:'da'
});
```

Now the form have a value for the property `From` and the model binding will be able to send it to the controller. In your case the value was assigned to a input named `startDate`, as long I could understand, this property `startDate` it is not in your model.

I hope it helps.

Comment: You're the reason I didn't turn bald in an early stage - thank you!

Comment: This is nonsense and has nothing to do with OP's issue.